# Return value of __exit__

Tags: python, with-statement, contextmanager

I understand that

- `__enter__` and `__exit__` are used to implement a context manager.
- if an exception occurs in a `with` statement, the exception's type, value and traceback are passed to the `__exit__` method.
- `__exit__` can handle the exception:

  1. Returning `True`: the exception is gracefully handled.
  2. Returning anything else: the `with` statement raises the exception

---

**I came across the following `__exit__` method. Is the return statement  redundant?**

```
def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
    self.close()
    return type == None
```

since it seems to me that,

- If no exception occurred, `type` will naturally be `None`, so `__exit__` returns true. Nothing is raised.
- If an exception did occur, `type` is set to the actual exception type, so `__exit__` returns false. The exception is raised as is.

Comment: That's a confusing `return` statement on more than one level. Never use `== None` when you can use `is None` instead. But yes, just remove that `return` line altogether for all that it is worth.

Comment: It's also confusing when you name method argument `type`. Because `type` is already build-in keyword. it's better to use `exc_type` as it don't confuse and not shadows build-in keyword.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Yes, that return statement is redundant. Only when `type` is **not** `None`  does the return value matter.

From the [`object.__exit__()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__exit__):

> If an exception is supplied, and the method wishes to suppress the exception (i.e., prevent it from being propagated), it should return a true value. Otherwise, the exception will be processed normally upon exit from this method.

Note that a *true value* will suppress the exception; so `1` or `"Handled!"` would also work, not just `True`.

Removing that `return` line would result in `None` being returned instead, and the functionality would remain unchanged. Readability would be improved however, because that `return type == None` statement is just confusing on multiple levels (why not use `type is None` for example?).